# delayed_job handle_asynchronously equivalent in Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, delayed-job

I am in midst of shifting ActiveJob handling for a Rails 5 application from `delayed_job` to `sidekiq`. One small issue, I have certain model method `doXYZ`, after which this enforcement is present.

```
handle_asynchronously :doXYZ, run_at: proc { |i| i.run_at_time }
```

What would be an equivalent enforcement in Sidekiq ?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no replacement of `handle_asynchronously` in Sidekiq,
But you can do like that https://gist.github.com/cristianbica/7706419

Comment: Already went through that. Two questions :
    1. Is it tested in production somewhere?
    2. Is there a cleaner alternative ?